# C Program to calculate sgpa using structures

Tags: c, data-structures

(QW) Write a well documented modular C program to compute SGPA of 2 students of particular semester containing 3 courses, suitably using structures.

Getting garbage value as output scanning of elements goes perfectly but when it comes to printing it displays random number as output, Is the sgpa calculator part of the code correct?

```
//reaplced courses with 3 and no of students with 2
#include<stdio.h>
struct studentlist
{
    int Rno;
    char name[20];
    int course_marks[8];
}S[2];
int main()
{
    
    int sgpa[2];
    printf("ENTER DETAILS\n");
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        printf("enter details of student %d\n",i);
        scanf("%d %s",&S[i].Rno,S[i].name);
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            printf("enter marks coursenumber %d \n",j);
            scanf("%d",S[i].course_marks[j]);
        }
        
    }
    //printing details
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        printf("details of student %d are \n",i);
        printf("%d %s",S[i].Rno,S[i].name);
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            printf("coursewise marks for studenet %d are\n",j);
            printf("%d\n",S[i].course_marks[j]);
        }
    }
    printf(" \n\n ");
    //sgpa calculation
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            sgpa[j]=0;
            sgpa[j]+=S[i].course_marks;
        }
    }
    //printing
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",sgpa[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Is the sgpa calculator part of the code correct?" No.

Comment: Scanning will not go perfectly in your new code. Please do not break question by editing.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `S[j].course_marks` is wrong.

It is an array and it will be converted to a pointer in expressions here.

It seems the lines

```
            scanf("%d",S[j].course_marks);
            printf("%d\n",S[i].course_marks);
            sgpa[j]+=S[i].course_marks;
```

should be

```
            scanf("%d",&S[i].course_marks[j]);
            printf("%d\n",S[i].course_marks[j]);
            sgpa[j]+=S[i].course_marks[j];
```

Also the loop

```
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            sgpa[j]=0;
            sgpa[j]+=S[i].course_marks;
        }
```

is bad because it accesses `spga[2]` while `spga` has only 2 elements `spga[0]` and `spga[1]`.

Also it looks weird even if it weren't out-of-range access and

```
            sgpa[j]=0;
            sgpa[j]+=S[i].course_marks;
```

is equivalent to

```
            sgpa[j]=S[i].course_marks;
```

You should rethink the algorithm here.